# Erro "Maximum call stack size exceeded" ao instanciar objeto

Tags: typescript, ionic2, angular

Tenho as seguintes classes em um app Ionic 2

```
export class JobIteractionsModel {

    public _idJob: number;
    get idJob() { return this._idJob }
    set idJob(idJob: number) { this._idJob = idJob }

    public _dataHoraInicio: Date;
    get dataHoraInicio() { return this._dataHoraInicio }
    set dataHoraInicio(dataHoraInicio: Date) { this._dataHoraInicio = dataHoraInicio }

    public _dataHoraFim: Date;
    get dataHoraFim() { return this._dataHoraFim }
    set dataHoraFim(dataHoraFim: Date) { this._dataHoraFim = dataHoraFim }

    public _valorTotal: number;
    get valorTotal() { return this._valorTotal }
    set valorTotal(valorTotal: number) { this._valorTotal = valorTotal }
}



import { JobIteractionsModel } from './JobIteractionsModel';
export class JobModel {

    public _id: number;
    get id() { return this._id }
    set id(id: number) { this._id = id }

    public _cliente: string;
    get cliente() { return this._cliente }
    set cliente(cliente: string) { this._cliente = cliente }

    public _telefone: string;
    get telefone() { return this._telefone }
    set telefone(telefone: string) { this._telefone = telefone }

    public _email: string;
    get email() { return this._email }
    set email(email: string) { this._email = email }

    public _descricao: string;
    get descricao() { return this._descricao }
    set descricao(descricao: string) { this._descricao = descricao }

    public _interacoes: JobIteractionsModel[];
    get interacoes() { return this.interacoes }
    set interacoes(interacoes: JobIteractionsModel[]) { this._interacoes = interacoes }

    public _adicionaInteracao(interacao: JobIteractionsModel) {
        this.interacoes.push(interacao);
    }

    public _deletaInteracao(index) {
        this.interacoes.splice(index, 1);
    }

    public _subtotal: number;
    get subtotal() { return this.subtotal }
    set subtotal(subtotal: number) { this._subtotal = subtotal }

    public _desconto: number;
    get desconto() { return this.desconto }
    set desconto(desconto: number) { this._desconto = desconto }

    public _total: number;
    get total() { return this.total }
    set total(total: number) { this._total = total }

}
```

Quando crio uma nova instância da classe **JobModel** e verifico no inspecionador de elementos do Chrome, a propriedade **interacoes**, o erro "Maximum call stack size exceeded" está sendo exibido.

O mesmo erro é exibido ao tentar utilizar o método **_adicionaInteracao** de uma instância da classe **JobModel**.

[image: Erro exibido ao depurar no Chrome]

[image: Erro exibido no console]

Não entendi ainda o motivo, mas quando invoco o método **_adicionaInteracao()**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entra no método
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E depois a execução vai para esta linha, e fica executando-a recursivamente até dar o erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qualquer ajuda será muito bem vinda.

Comment: o console do Chrome não aponta algum erro?

Comment: Mostra o que é lançado no console

Comment: Talvez relevante: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12735

Comment: Editei a pergunta incluindo um print do console.

Comment: @mercador, Giovane incluí o print do console e novos prints para detalhar melhor o problema. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado a todos, consegui resolver aqui.

Era erro no nome da propriedade **_interacoes**, na classe **JobModel**. Basicamente eu alterei de:

```
public _interacoes: JobIteractionsModel[];
get interacoes() { return this.interacoes } //<- Esta linha estava causando a recursividade
set interacoes(int: JobIteractionsModel[]) { this._interacoes = int }
```

Para:

```
public _interacoes: JobIteractionsModel[];
get interacoes() { return this._interacoes }
set interacoes(int: JobIteractionsModel[]) { this._interacoes = int }
```

E depois alterei a declaração do array **_interacoes** inicializando-o.

```
public _interacoes: JobIteractionsModel[] = [];
get interacoes() { return this._interacoes }
set interacoes(int: JobIteractionsModel[]) { this._interacoes = int }
```